# How to pass parameters from a s:a to the action in struts2

Tags: struts2

I'm using Struts2. I need to pass a parameter from my jsp to the action. The parameter is different depending on which link we want to see although the action is the same. I don't know how to do this... My code without passing parameters is this:

```
<% if (usuario.getComputeEngines().size() > 0) { 
                int contador = 1;
                Long idCE;
                for (int i=0; i < usuario.getComputeEngines().size(); i++){
                    idCE = usuario.getComputeEngines().get(i).getIdComputeEngine();
                    %>
                <td width="50%" align="center" valign="top">
                    <br clear=all>
                    <s:a href="%{CE}"><img src="images/casa<%out.println(contador); %>
                    .jpg" border="0"></s:a>
                    <br><%=i%>
                    <br>
                </td>
```

The parameter i need to pass to the action is i. It's just a number. How could I do this? 
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3):

```
<s:url ="CE" action="action">
        <s:param name="name" value="value"/>
</s:url>
```

This is only part of it, and it needs an id. You need to then associate the url with the anchor tag:

```
<s:url id="myUrl" action="action">
        <s:param name="name" value="value"/>
</s:url>

<s:a href="%{myUrl}"><img src="images/casa<%out.println(contador); %>
                .jpg" border="0"></s:a>
```

You can put as many  tags in there as you want. I've also noticed that the form...

```
<s:param name="name" value="value"/>
```

...sometimes does not work and I tend to use:

```
<s:param name="name">value</s:param>
```

Comment: Thanks for that comment about <s:param name="name" value="value"/> not working sometimes. That helped me resolve the issue that I was having. <s:param name="name">value</s:param> worked for me. Strange !! Any idea why? Is that an undocumented feature? Or, is it documented?

Comment: Not entirely sure. I've tended to move away from using the struts tags in favor of JSP EL and JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a parameter in

```
    <s:url ="CE" action="action">
            <s:param name="name" value="value"/>
    </s:url>
```